# How to keep the focus on a WPF desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would like to create a windows desktop application that can be used by my daughter. The use case is that I give her a keyboard and I start this application so she can press any keys that she wants. The application can display something (e.g. the pressed letters in big, or pictures, etc.) and prevents my daughter to delete/modify things from/on my computer.

I have some difficulties with the special key handling. I can disable the ALT+F4 with the following technique but I cannot control the ALT+TAB and Win keys that way.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(OnButtonKeyDown);
}

protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt && e.SystemKey == Key.F4)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

I found [an article](http://geekswithblogs.net/aghausman/archive/2009/04/26/disable-special-keys-in-win-app-c.aspx) which disables such functionalities when the application is active but I think it quite fragile for non-expected application exit.

What I finally did is a workaround which works but does not feel too professional.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Activate();
    this.Focus();
}
```

As you can see I created a timer which brings the focus back from time to time. This way if you press the Win Key or the ALT+TAB it will brings the application back.

How can I keep the focus on my application on a more professional way? I am thinking about a solution which detects when the application loses the focus (for any reasons) and sets the focus back.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think there's the even `OnFocusLost` which you might implement. Not sure if it works with all WIn-key and stuff, though.

Comment: Why not just create another user, where all it has is this program and everything else is locked down? Then you just Switch User into it, and when you want to get back, Switch User back (and enter your password)

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`Window.Deactivated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.deactivated.aspx) event and re-activate it to achieve what you want:

```
this.Deactivated += (s, e) => this.Activate();
```

What you would also like would be to make the app full-screen and within the app create a hidden shortcut key. After you press that, you are prompted to type a password and then you can close the app. Otherwise, it will be a hassle to close the app for you as well.

Comment: Hi @fᴀʀʜᴀɴ-aɴᴀᴍ! Thanks for your time. Where should I place this code? I put it into the `MainWindow` constructor but it does not help in resetting the focus. I can easily switch application that way. For your other suggestions: yes, I did that. :)

Comment: This code doesn't work. It might work when we try to focus one window in our app. But not outside our application.

Answer (score 0):

In my XAML markup I added the event listener for deactivation.

```
<Window x:Class="Desktop.MainWindow"
        Deactivated="MainWindow_OnDeactivated">
...
</Window>
```

In code behind, I added the event handler for reactivation.

```
namespace Desktop
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void MainWindow_OnDeactivated(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
      Activate();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @konrad-viltersten! Have you tried it? I am asking because I added to [my current version (locally)](https://github.com/gabor-meszaros/bravo) and it does not work for me. I use VS 2015 Community edition, Windows 10 and I tried the VS debug build from Visual Studio. If it works for you that would be also helpful because it means that the problem is in my setup.

Comment: @GaborMeszaros I have tried, yes. First I tried the focus event but that didn't pulled the window back to the view. But this one did. I'm on Win 8, if it's of any difference. What exactly do you mean when you say that it doesn't work? WHat happens? Do you hit the break-point in the handler? And then...?

Comment: I uploaded two videos to YouTube [Timer solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iy0AwvciBaE) and [Deactivated solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=af6Ayg86k6I). In the second case when you press the Win key it stays there. In case of the Timer solution it brings the application back to the top and gives the focus back to it.

Comment: @GaborMeszaros I haven't tested it with Win, perhaps. I might have just clicked away from the window and then it got back into the view by itself.  You **could** remap the keys but that's more of an ugly work-around, rather then a solution. I have nothing else at the moment. Your issue is difficult because, technically speaking, you're trying to eliminate other windows in a multi-windows-GUI... Have you seen [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203902.aspx) (totally untested)?

Answer (score 0):

***Use*** following window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStackOverflowTempProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="525"
    DataContext="{RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData}"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfStackOverflowTempProject" 
    WindowState="Maximized"   ResizeMode="NoResize"  
    Topmost="True"        
    >
```

> ***`Topmost="True"`  should do the trick functional point of view. `WindowState="Maximized"` & `ResizeMode="NoResize"` to  restrict
>   interaction with other windows.***

Comment: Hi @kylo-ren! It does not work for me. I tend to believe in that the issue connects to Windows 10. I am going to update the original post with this information. I added two videos to @konrad-viltersten 's answer. Your solution gives me exactly the same result that his solution gives.

Comment: @GaborMeszaros I don;t think so that our solution can produce same results. Theoretically if a window is activated doesn't necessarily means that it will be the top most window or it will be the focused window. The very problem with other solution posted were they are not using anytime delay between Deactivating by user and then Activating   by code. hence the activation will happen even before alt+tab result result renders. and alt+tab result will ultimately will be visible on the screen. I've tested my code in window 10 and it was working. not sure why it is not working for you.

Comment: @GaborMeszaros I don't think DispatcherTimer solution is complete either. Try win + m key. or user can minimize the window.